# For the series 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 6, what are the next terms in the sequence? What is the nth term?

Tags: numbers, logic, sequence, series

i want to know the pattern for the above series in order to write the code for above series.
I am thinking that the above series is mix of two different series 1,2,4,6,...and 1,2,2,..
Please help me with this sequence and also tell whether i am  thinking in correct way or not.

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: Questions of this kind do not have objective answers without further restrictions. There is no way to determine whether you are correct without specified limits on applicable sequence-forming rules.

Answer (score 0):

logic :-- 
series 1-> Prime-1 i.e. [1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 18, 22, 28, 30, 36.....] 
series 2-> Number Series i.e. [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5.....] 
final output -> Alternate Series i.e. [1 1 2 2 4 2 6 3 10 3 12 3 16 4 18 4 22 4 28 4....]

**Note :** 
There might be another logic but by the given Question, this series can be identified by below program.. 
 **Please do not use for any competition Test/Exam**

import math 
global li_prime;global li_series;xp=0
def prime(size):
    global li_prime;count = 2; 
    while len(li_prime)
        isprime = True        
        for x in range(2, int(math.sqrt(count) + 1)): 
            if count % x == 0: 
                isprime = False 
                break        
        if isprime:
            li_prime.append(count-1)      
        count += 1 
def series(size): 
    global li_series 
    for i in range(size+1): 
        for j in range(i): 
            li_series.append(i) 
        if len(li_series)>size: 
            break  
def main(): 
    global xp 
    global li_prime 
    global li_series 
    testcase=int(input('')) 
    for I in range(testcase): 
        li_series=[] 
        li_prime=[] 
        size=int(input('')) 
        prime(size) 
        series(size) 
        li_prime=li_prime[:size] 
        li_series=li_series[:size] 
        lc=[] 
        for i in range(size//2+1): 
            lc.append(str(li_prime[i])) 
            lc.append(str(li_series[i])) 
        lc=lc[:size] 
main()

Answer (score 0):

It is series whose greatest common divisior (gcd) is 1 also known as Euler's Totient Function.

series format = {1 1 2 2 4 2 6 32 ..... 168 80 216 120 164 100}

Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

//n is the input for the size of the series
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
            System.out.print(calSeriesVal(j)+" ");
        }
}


private static int calDivisor(int a, int b)
{
    if (a == 0)
        return b;
    return calDivisor(b % a, a);
}

private static int calSeriesVal(int n)
{
    int val = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (calDivisor(i, n) == 1)
            val++;
    return val;
}
```